# Can we add regular meta tags to the JQuery mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, meta-tags

I just want to confirm can we add the normal HTML meta tags to JQuery mobile like,

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="description " />
<meta name="KEYWORDS" content="" />
<meta name="RATING" content="General" />
<meta name="REVISIT-AFTER" content="30 days" />
<meta name="author" content="author name" />
<meta name="robots" content="NOODP" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Becase I don't see any where we can include this or not ? Even JQuery mobile site has not added to their site (I checked by view source thier page). Could anyone please confirm above meta tag will affect or not to the JQuery mobile site apart from their setup ?

Comment: Of course you can. But keyword is rarely used now since search engines technology has evolved and became more advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya sure. **Meta tags** will not affect to Jquery mobile indeed they will enhance the search engine optimization(SEO) of your site.

**HTML meta tags** are officially page data tags that lie between the open and closing head tags in the HTML code of a document.

*Meta elements are typically used to specify page description, keywords, author of the document, last modified, and other metadata.*

**The META tag** is primarily used to help search engines better index a document by supplying additional information about the document. The types of additional information that META tags can provide include an author's name, a description or short abstract of a document, or a set of keywords for indexing a document. Providing this type of additional information should increase the chance that users will find your documents -- the information they want -- on the Web. In addition to providing indexing information, META tags can also be used to refresh a Web page or to redirect a user from one Web page to another.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. Yes, you can put them in the head, but the only head that is looked at is the head of the opening page. When you change pages, JQM simply swaps out what is between the data-role="page" divs. I'm hoping there is a way around this, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Title: Add the title to the data-role="page" div, so you have div data-role="page" id="YourPage ID" data-title="Your Page Title". IT should be noted that jqm WILL apply the title to the DOM even if you don't do this, but I do both to be on the safe side.